# Получение части текста после точки из xml

Tags: php, xml

Есть файл отчёта 1c в xml формате, каким образом можно вывести тип документа после точки `"v8:DocumentObject.Тип документа"` Тип документа может быть уникальным.

Пример xml:

```
<V8Exch:Data>
        <v8:ConstantValueManager.ИспользоватьДокументыПоступления>
            <v8:Value>true</v8:Value>
        </v8:ConstantValueManager.ИспользоватьДокументыПоступления>
        <v8:DocumentObject.РеализацияТоваровУслуг>
</V8Exch:Data>
```

Пример кода:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$typed = $xml->xpath('//v8:'DocumentObject);
foreach($typed as $t) {
   echo $t;
}
```

Полный xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<V8Exch:_1CV8DtUD xmlns:V8Exch="http://www.1c.ru/V8/1CV8DtUD/" xmlns:core="http://v8.1c.ru/data" xmlns:v8="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <V8Exch:Data>
        <v8:ConstantValueManager.ИспользоватьДокументыПоступления>
            <v8:Value>true</v8:Value>
        </v8:ConstantValueManager.ИспользоватьДокументыПоступления>
        <v8:DocumentObject.РеализацияТоваровУслуг>
            <v8:Ref>ab0cdaba-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Ref>
            <v8:DeletionMark>false</v8:DeletionMark>
            <v8:Date>2021-10-29T23:59:59</v8:Date>
            <v8:Number>0000-000001</v8:Number>
            <v8:Posted>true</v8:Posted>
            <v8:ВидОперации>Товары</v8:ВидОперации>
            <v8:Организация xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Организации">12bb3b0b-3823-11ec-bb94-000000000003</v8:Организация>
            <v8:Склад xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Склады">bc83a16d-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:Склад>
            <v8:ПодразделениеОрганизации xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ПодразделенияОрганизаций">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ПодразделениеОрганизации>
            <v8:ДеятельностьНаПатенте>false</v8:ДеятельностьНаПатенте>
            <v8:Патент xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Патенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Патент>
            <v8:Контрагент xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">ab0cdab6-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Контрагент>
            <v8:ДоговорКонтрагента xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ДоговорыКонтрагентов">ab0cdab7-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:ДоговорКонтрагента>
            <v8:СпособЗачетаАвансов>Автоматически</v8:СпособЗачетаАвансов>
            <v8:ТипЦен xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ТипыЦенНоменклатуры">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ТипЦен>
            <v8:ВалютаДокумента xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Валюты">6f5dc185-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ВалютаДокумента>
            <v8:КурсВзаиморасчетов>1</v8:КурсВзаиморасчетов>
            <v8:КратностьВзаиморасчетов>1</v8:КратностьВзаиморасчетов>
            <v8:СуммаВключаетНДС>true</v8:СуммаВключаетНДС>
            <v8:УдалитьУчитыватьНДС>false</v8:УдалитьУчитыватьНДС>
            <v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовСКонтрагентом xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1488ff-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовСКонтрагентом>
            <v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоАвансам xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b148900-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоАвансам>
            <v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b148969-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаРасчетовПоТаре>
            <v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаДоходовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаДоходовПоТаре>
            <v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаРасходовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:УдалитьСчетУчетаРасходовПоТаре>
            <v8:УдалитьСтатьяДоходовИРасходовПоТаре xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ПрочиеДоходыИРасходы">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:УдалитьСтатьяДоходовИРасходовПоТаре>
            <v8:СчетНаОплатуПокупателю>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СчетНаОплатуПокупателю>
            <v8:Грузоотправитель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Грузоотправитель>
            <v8:Грузополучатель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Грузополучатель>
            <v8:АдресДоставки/>
            <v8:БанковскийСчетОрганизации xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.БанковскиеСчета">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:БанковскийСчетОрганизации>
            <v8:СуммаДокумента>50</v8:СуммаДокумента>
            <v8:Ответственный xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Пользователи">aa00559e-ad84-4494-88fd-f0826edc46f0</v8:Ответственный>
            <v8:Комментарий/>
            <v8:РучнаяКорректировка>false</v8:РучнаяКорректировка>
            <v8:Руководитель xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Руководитель>
            <v8:ГлавныйБухгалтер xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ГлавныйБухгалтер>
            <v8:ОтпускПроизвел xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ОтпускПроизвел>
            <v8:УдалитьЗаРуководителяПоПриказу/>
            <v8:УдалитьЗаГлавногоБухгалтераПоПриказу/>
            <v8:ЗаЗаказчикаНаОсновании/>
            <v8:ДоверенностьНомер/>
            <v8:ДоверенностьДата>0001-01-01T00:00:00</v8:ДоверенностьДата>
            <v8:ДоверенностьВыдана/>
            <v8:ДоверенностьЧерезКого/>
            <v8:ВидЭлектронногоДокумента>ТОРГ12Продавец</v8:ВидЭлектронногоДокумента>
            <v8:ДокументБезНДС>true</v8:ДокументБезНДС>
            <v8:ЗаРуководителяНаОсновании xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ОснованияПраваПодписи">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ЗаРуководителяНаОсновании>
            <v8:ЗаГлавногоБухгалтераНаОсновании xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ОснованияПраваПодписи">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ЗаГлавногоБухгалтераНаОсновании>
            <v8:Перевозчик xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Контрагенты">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:Перевозчик>
            <v8:МаркаАвтомобиля/>
            <v8:РегистрационныйЗнакАвтомобиля/>
            <v8:Водитель/>
            <v8:ВодительскоеУдостоверение/>
            <v8:КраткоеНаименованиеГруза/>
            <v8:СопроводительныеДокументы/>
            <v8:ДеятельностьНаТорговомСборе>false</v8:ДеятельностьНаТорговомСборе>
            <v8:ОтветственныйЗаОформление xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.ФизическиеЛица">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ОтветственныйЗаОформление>
            <v8:СведенияОТранспортировкеИГрузе/>
            <v8:ПеревозкаАвтотранспортом>false</v8:ПеревозкаАвтотранспортом>
            <v8:ЕстьМаркируемаяПродукцияГИСМ>false</v8:ЕстьМаркируемаяПродукцияГИСМ>
            <v8:НомерЧекаККМ>0</v8:НомерЧекаККМ>
            <v8:Товары>
                <v8:Номенклатура xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.Номенклатура">ab0cdab9-38e9-11ec-bb95-000000000003</v8:Номенклатура>
                <v8:КоличествоМест>0</v8:КоличествоМест>
                <v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторЕдиницИзмерения">bc83a16f-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:ЕдиницаИзмерения>
                <v8:Коэффициент>1</v8:Коэффициент>
                <v8:Количество>10</v8:Количество>
                <v8:Цена>5</v8:Цена>
                <v8:Сумма>50</v8:Сумма>
                <v8:СтавкаНДС>БезНДС</v8:СтавкаНДС>
                <v8:СуммаНДС>0</v8:СуммаНДС>
                <v8:СчетУчета xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1488c2-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчета>
                <v8:ПереданныеСчетУчета xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:ПереданныеСчетУчета>
                <v8:СчетДоходов xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489ac-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетДоходов>
                <v8:Субконто xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НоменклатурныеГруппы">bc83a170-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:Субконто>
                <v8:СчетУчетаНДСПоРеализации xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489b1-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетУчетаНДСПоРеализации>
                <v8:СчетРасходов xsi:type="v8:ChartOfAccountsRef.Хозрасчетный">5b1489af-0ae4-11e9-80ed-0050569f2e9f</v8:СчетРасходов>
                <v8:ДокументОприходования xsi:nil="true"/>
                <v8:Себестоимость>0</v8:Себестоимость>
                <v8:НомерГТД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.НомераГТД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:НомерГТД>
                <v8:СтранаПроисхождения xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.СтраныМира">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:СтранаПроисхождения>
                <v8:КиЗ_ГИСМ xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КонтрольныеЗнакиГИСМ">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КиЗ_ГИСМ>
                <v8:КодТНВЭД xsi:type="v8:CatalogRef.КлассификаторТНВЭД">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</v8:КодТНВЭД>
            </v8:Товары>
        </v8:DocumentObject.РеализацияТоваровУслуг>
    </V8Exch:Data>
    <PredefinedData/>
</V8Exch:_1CV8DtUD>
```

Comment: а заголовок у xml есть?

Comment: @splash58 Добавил полный xml

Comment: `substring-after(//V8Exch:Data//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'DocumentObject')]/local-name(), 'DocumentObject.')` Не знаю, будет ли работать в php

Comment: на каком яп написано?

Comment: это xpath.  Но может зависеть от реализации

Comment: Simpltexml xpath, кажется не понимает текстовых функций. Просто получите элемент, а остальное ручками. Или используйте domdocument xpath execute, а не query